# what tests to use to validate a dynamic factor model obtained using nowcasting package in r

Tags: r, model, modeling

I used the nowcast function from R package to use dynamic factor model to nowcast GDP using the extracted factors. I Have tried multiple combination of the initial variables and finally obtained this model which all variables in it seems significant and teh ales obtained for my variable of interest is acceptable.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4u8U.png)
But I can't find any reference about what tests on residuals that  I need to do in order to validate this model.
I am really struggling and have been stuck in this for a month, I need to submit my graduation project this weekend and I really need this model to work. so any help will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

1. **Update 1:**

This is teh acf plot n residuals suggested by the same package nowcasting, I think my model passes that test and therefore I can use it. right?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6Unl.png)

Comment: Have you read the seminal papers on nowcasting (Giannone 2008)? Looks like they do an ACF on the residuals.

Comment: @BillO'Brien thank you for your reply, That is the only test I need to execute, right?

Comment: Rai - this method was created well after my last econometrics class, so I can't say for sure. In fact today is the first I've heard of it. Just trying to point you toward a reliable source ;)

Comment: I suggest asking on CrossValidated as it's more of a stats question than R programming question.

Comment: @BillO'Brien thank you for your advice and I checked the article, it is a main reference and  a reliable source and it is confirmed by the package itself, so thank you for your answer.